# Dialogue randomly asking for a stored WIFI password after resuming from suspend

Tags: wireless, network-manager, suspend, 20.04, kde

Often (something like every 5th-10th time) after waking up from suspend/sleep I see a dialogue asking me to enter the WPA2 password for my home WIFI network.

I know that the password is stored properly, since it usually helps to just click away this dialogue and click the "Connect" button of near the SSID in Networks, which then works without asking for the password. Until, of course, some other time, it happens again when resuming from sleep.

I cannot figure out which this happens (some racing condition perhaps?). Maybe anybody has an idea how to fix this irritating issue.

Comment: sudo apt install nm-connection-editor, open from terminal, nm-connection-editor and then select the wifi-> Edit the selected connection -> General -> Enable All users may connect to this network
OR in Wi-Fi Security on the password field on the right side there is a small icon, click that and select STORE THE PASSWORD FOR ALL USERS

Comment: if you're using KDE then this could be the something to try...

in Settings -> Connections -> Select your Wi-Fi -> Enable All users may connect to this network

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this solution/workaround elsewhere and tried it. At the moment, the network is enabled for all users. But I also don't think it would have to do with a setting, since I am asked for the password randomly (sometimes yes, mostly not).

Comment: The same thing happened to me, I have VPN which connects automatically after boot and suspend and if the password is not stored for all users, then sometimes I get notification that I need to write the password

Comment: Well, I followed your instructions and, unfortunately, it still happens.